# Show Custom Message for remote validation success response

Tags: validation, asp.net-mvc-3, remote-validation

I am using remote validation to check the availability of username during registration for my asp.net mvc 3 applicaion (C#).

I am using MVC remote Attribute validation as:

```
[Remote("IsUserNameAvailable", "User")]
public string UserName { get; set; }
```

I need to show the message on two conditions:

1. Show error message "Username not available" - Failure Condition
2. Show Success message "Username available" - Success Condition

I am able to show the Failure Condition's message without any issue like:

```
return Json("Username not available", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

But for Success Condition, I need to send true in response(not with the custom message) as:

```
 return Json(true, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

How can i show custom message for Success Condition of Remote validation?

Answer (score 2):

see this link...
[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10702914/do-something-on-success-response-for-remote-validation-in-mvc/10706595#10706595)

One way to achieve that is to add a custom HTTP response header from the validation action:

```
public ActionResult IsUserNameAvailable(string username)
{
if (IsValid(username))
{
    // add the id that you want to communicate to the client
    // in case of validation success as a custom HTTP header
    Response.AddHeader("X-ID", "123");
    return Json(true, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}

return Json("The username is invalid", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Now on the client we obviously have a standard form and an input field for the username:

```
@model MyViewModel
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.EditorFor(x => x.UserName)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.UserName)
    <button type="submit">OK</button>
}
```

and now the last piece of the puzzle is to attach a complete handler to the remote rule on the username field:

```
$(function () {
$('#UserName').rules().remote.complete = function (xhr) {
    if (xhr.status == 200 && xhr.responseText === 'true') {
        // validation succeeded => we fetch the id that
        // was sent from the server
        var id = xhr.getResponseHeader('X-ID');

        // and of course we do something useful with this id
        alert(id);
    }
};
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you able to return an object (which will be serialised to Json)?

Such as:

```
var answer = new { success = true, message = "Username available" };
return Json(answer, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

Then you can parse this in the view.

Also, if you do it this way, but the username is NOT available, you could add a few suggested usernames too.

e.g.

```
// pretend they chose "dave"
List<string> alternativeNames = new List<string>() { "dave1", "dave2" };
var answer = new { success = false, message = "Username not available", alternatives = alternativeNames };
return Json(answer, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

Comment: how do i parse this for Remote Validation? Remote Validation is in jquery.validate.min.js. How do i rewrite that part?